# Locating pointes on map to country

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, coordinates, country

I have a coordinates file, json data of points around the world like this `{lat: 123 , lng: 123}`.

I use Leaflet map and i want to marker on the map the number of points that i have for each country in the world.

For example, if I have 3 point in Egypt, I want to draw 1 marker on the map in center of Egypt with label : 3.

How can I do that? is there any data of countries borders coordinates that I can scan and find the country of each point?

Thanks

Comment: You can use reverse geocoding, which takes the location data and returns a JSON file containing textual details about the place. For example: https://locationiq.com/sandbox/geocoding/reverse

Comment: Perhaps a combination of Natural Earth administrative borders and some TurfJS for the point-in-polygon queries, with some Poyllabel for the polygon centroids.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any data of countries borders coordinates that I can scan and find the country of each point?

Yes, here is a data source for geojson of all country polygon boundaries: https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/World_Countries_(Generalized)/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=pgeojson ([preview](https://gavinr.github.io/geojson-viewer/?url=https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/World_Countries_(Generalized)/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson)) ([more info](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2b93b06dc0dc4e809d3c8db5cb96ba69))

And here is a source of center point data for those countries: https://github.com/gavinr/world-countries-centroids